# Why does airflow's `last run` date not actually show the last run date?

Tags: airflow

In the dags listing `\admin` I see my dag and the `last run` column shows `2021-04-30 19:31` which is a run I triggered manually. But going to `/admin/taskinstance/` it shows it actually ran on schedule at `2021-05-01 03:50` (according to the docs I expected it to show about 1 hour later, at `2021-05-01 04:50` which is what the database shows).

So what gives? Why does airflow not actually show the last run date in `\admin`?

For reference, here's my dag definition:

```
ranking_generator = models.DAG(
    dag_id="activity_ranking_generator",
    schedule_interval="50 3 * * *",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 28),
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
)
```

Comment: Can you please add screenshots. I'm not sure I follow on what exactly is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, the date shown in the dag listing seems a day late. You can see it when you go to the `task instances` (browse - task instances) listing, the `execution date` is always 1 day before the `start date`, it's the `start date` that shows when it actually ran.. I'm guessing the `execution date` (what is shown as `Last run` in the dag listing) shows when it was *scheduled* and it executes 1 day *after* that date (it's a daily task) so that's why it seems wrong.. Had read about this but still got confused. Anyway, looks good now.